# Why would a computer stop working until a PSU is temporarily replaced

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure

I had a few out of the ordinary power outage, I say out of the ordinary because from what I recall, computer lost power due to the UPS battery depletion after the recovery of a first power loss.

Once the power came back, I attempted to power on the computer but it wouldn't do anything, as if the powe switch was disconnected. The power led was lit on the motherboard.

I went through my usual diagnostic routine to find out the culprit, starting by disconnecting all USB cables, all PCIe cards, removing the GPU, removing the case cables, clearing the CMOS. Even after all of these steps, it still wouldn't power on and the PSU had been switched on & off at multiple time during that time since I was trying to remove the least amount of component as possible while I was running the tests.

At that point, I decided to switch PSU since it could almost only be that, I would have received some motherboard sounds otherwise, unless the motherboard was actually fried.

Upon switching the PSU and adding power, the computer powered itself on without any intervention, I didn't had to short-circuit the power switch pins or anything.

At this point, just for the sake of it, I disconnected the PSU and retried the old one since the steps were very fast at that point and the old the computer worked with the old PSU as well.

Just to make sure it is clear :

- The computer had the exact same components with the old PSU, and power was indeed delivered which could be confirmed by the power led on the motherboard.
- Nothing else was changed beside replugging the ATX and auxiliary cables from both PSU and swapping the powercord from the same power outlet to one PSU to another.

It sounds like some kind of soft PSU failure, I just don't understand how changing it would have brought it back to life. If it was a motherboard failure, I don't understand how having a different PSU would have changed anything. The computer power had been completely shutted down for a minimum of 15s when the original PSU was still in place and it still wouldn't boot.

What could have happened and would have there been better steps than changing the PSU to 'revive' the old one / or correct the motherboard state.

Thanks

Comment: If swapping the PSUs was the only time you did any break&make power connections, then that could have been the fix.  For whatever reason remaking connections (i.e. unplugging and plugging back in) can resolve various electrical contact issues.

Comment: @sawdust the power cord was indeed disconnected before doing the PSU swap (I wanted to make sure the problem didn't come from a faulty UPS or outlet)

Comment: I was not referring to the AC power cord, but rather the DC connections to the motherboard.

Comment: Some power supplies have built-in protections against various things like shorts, surges, and etc.  Some of these will cause it to not work for a certain amount of time afterwards.  Sometimes it has to be completely unplugged.  Some have thermal protection so if a short circuit happens it heats something up and until it cools off it won't work again.